# openlog() and syslog() warning

Tags: 8

After Cron ran  and clean all cashes in drupal 8 I get this:

Warning: openlog() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/inatcent/public_html/core/modules/syslog/src/Logger/SysLog.php on line 59

Warning: syslog() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/inatcent/public_html/core/modules/syslog/src/Logger/SysLog.php on line 88

Warning: openlog() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/inatcent/public_html/core/modules/syslog/src/Logger/SysLog.php on line 59

Warning: syslog() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/inatcent/public_html/core/modules/syslog/src/Logger/SysLog.php on line 88

Does somebody know why this is happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages couldn't really be much clearer:

> openlog() **has been disabled** for security reasons

Emphasis mine.

So the functions have been disabled in your PHP config. To use them, you'll need to change your PHP config and remove `openlog` and `syslog` from the `disable_functions` directive.

If you're on shared hosting, you probably don't have this kind of access. In that case you should contact your host to ask them what their solution is, or move the site to a host that hasn't disabled those functions.

You could also obviously just disable the core Syslog module, and that will remove the errors; but, as yo'd expect, you won't be able to log to the syslog any more.

Comment: I send the ticket to host company hope all be good.

Comment: If it is not your own server, then there's not much point in having syslog enabled in the first place. You can't see those log files, so why bother logging to it?